# JDialog cannot be converted to frame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I want to make applcation where you can add students and then assign to each one of them 20 books.

I have 3 windows:
Main windows (JFrame)
List of books (JDialog)
Add a book (JDialog)

I have JFrame where I can see list of all students, then I click on "List of books" where I can see the list of all books in database (.txt file). So when I click on that button in JFrame, I open JDialog, that works fine. But now I want to add some books to the list, so I click on button "Add a book" in "List of Books" JDialog. So I just want to open another JDialog a top of previous JDialog.

So I the window "List of books" (which I opened from Main window) I want to open windows "Add a book".

Now when I do it by the same method as I open JDialog from JFrame, it shows error :

```
private void pridatKnihuJButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    addBookJDialog newwindow = new addBookJDialog(this, true);
    newwindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    newwindow.setVisible(true);
}
```

It shows :

**Incompatible types: addBookJDialog cannot be converted to Frame.**

Is there a simple way to do this ?
I'm creating those windows in NetBeans design function.

I found a few topics about opening some JDialog on another JDialog, but I didnt understand how to do it :/ There are 3 lines of code that opens another JDialog. Is there a way to just simple open it ?

Thanks.

Comment: to create only one JDialog, reuse that from anoter action (all clear must be  done before setVisible(false) is called)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the answer... or more likely, I finally understood the code everyone was posting :D 2 hours of looking for this :D

If someone have same question. The answer is:

When you click on button in your dialog button, then head to the ActionPerformed section of that button (double-click on that button in NetBeans design section).

and write this :

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    <target dialog> <optional name> = new <target dialog>(frame,true);
    <optional name (but same as above)>.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    <optional name (but same as above)>pridatzaznam.setVisible(true);
```

Import what is needs to be imported and there you go.

It'll probably need these two:
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

Example :

```
JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
    dialogIWantToOpen openthis = new dialogIWantToOpen(frame,true);
    openthis.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    openthis.setVisible(true);
```

Will open a dialog atop of your current dialog, but only if your current dialog was opened from JFrame.

If you want to open a dialog atop a dialog atop a dialog etc... it will probably need some editation after (JFrame) where

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
```

will probably have to be something like

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowsAncestor(SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this));
```

So this will open a dialog, that was opened from a dialog that was opened from a dialog that was opened from a JFrame. But I'm not sure if it will work. Didnt tried that.